# Compare current date to date string in a file using powershell

Tags: powershell, getdate

I am writing some PS scripts to log times into a text file, login.txt, using the following code:

```
$logdir = "C:\FOLDER"
$logfile = "$logdir\LastLogin.txt"
$user = $env:USERNAME
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
if (!(Test-Path $logdir)){New-Item -ItemType Directory $logdir}else{}
if (!(Test-Path $logfile)){New-Item $logfile}else{}
if (Get-Content $logfile | Select-String $user -Quiet){write-host "exists"}else{"$user - $date" | Add-Content -path $logfile}
(Get-Content $logfile) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$user.+$", "$user - $date"; } | Set-Content $logfile
```

This creates an entry in the text file like:

UserName - 01-01-1999

Using Powershell, I want to read the text file, compare the date, 01-01-1999, in the text file to the current date and if more than 30 days difference, extract the UserName to a variable to be used later in the script.

I would really appreciate any hints as to how I could do the following:

1. Compare the date in the text file to the current date.
2. If difference is more than 30 days, pick up UserName as a variable.

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Dates can be subtracted: `$diff = $($(Get-Date) - $date_file).Days` gets you the days between now and a variable called `$date_file` containing a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking all dates in the file with the help of a RegEx with named capture groups.

```
$logdir = "C:\FOLDER"
$logfile = Join-Path $logdir "LastLogin.txt"
$Days = -30
$Expires = (Get-Date).AddDays($Days)

Get-Content $logfile | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match "(?<User>[^ ]+) - (?<LastLogin>[0-9\-]+)") {
    $LastLogin = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches.LastLogin,"dd-MM-yyyy",$Null)
    if ( $Expires -gt $LastLogin ) {
      "{0} last login {1} is {2:0} days ago" -F $Matches.User, $Matches.LastLogin,
         (New-TimeSpan -Start $LastLogin -End (Get-Date) ).TotalDays
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output

```
username last login 31-12-1999 is 6690 days ago
```

Comment: Whoa! I didn't know you could name your capture groups!  That is awesome!

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon You can read more on the topic [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much.
This works perfectly.
And I can pull the username into a variable and proceed with the rest of the script.. thank you so much.
These RegEx look hard to understand.

Comment: To gain experience with RegEx I can recommand the site [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3mYZA8/1) It explains every single step very thorough. BTW the best tank is a [check marks as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or a vote up.

Comment: @LotPings - This indeed is very helpful. Much cleaner than the one I tried. Thanks for the pro-tip! :)

Comment: This is now working great. I have paired it up with my other script and deleting profiles nicely now.. lol.
I now need to remove the line of the user more than 30 days.
I have tried several methods, but as the get-content still has the file open, I haven`t succeeded yet. still working on it though.

Comment: Found it.. Added the following and it all works nicely now.
         $delstr = $Matches.User + " - " + $Matches.LastLogin
         $delstr
         $lines = Get-Content $logfile
         $first = $lines[0]
         $lines | where { $_ -ne $delstr } | out-file $logfile

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing that using [regex](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) (Regular Expressions). I will assume that the `username` which you get in your text file is `.(dot)` separated. For example, username looks like `john.doe` or `jason.smith` etc. And the entry in your text file looks like `john.doe - 01-01-1999` or `jason.smith - 02-02-1999`. Keeping these things in mind our approach would be -

1. Using a regex we would get the `username` and `date entry` into a single variable.
2. Next up, we will split the pattern we have got in step 1 into two parts i.e. the `username` part and the `date` part.
3. Next we take the date part and if the difference is more than 30 days, we would take the other part (`username`) and store it in a variable.

So the code would look something like this -

```
$arr = @() #defining an array to store the username with date
$pattern = "[a-z]*[.][a-z]*\s[-]\s[\d]{2}[-][\d]{2}[-][\d]{4}" #Regex pattern to match entires like "john.doe - 01-01-1999"

Get-Content $logfile | Foreach {if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
           $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
            }
        }
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value} #Storing the matched pattern in $arr


$UserNamewithDate = $arr.value -split ('\s[-]\s') #step 2 - Storing the username and date into a variable.

$array = @() #Defining the array that would store the final usernames based on the time difference.

for($i = 1; $i -lt $UserNamewithDate.Length;)
{
    $datepart = [Datetime]$UserNamewithDate[$i] #Casting the date part to [datetime] format
    $CurrentDate = Get-Date
    $diff = $CurrentDate - $datepart
    if ($diff.Days -gt 30)
    {
        $array += $UserNamewithDate[$i -1] #If the difference between current date and the date received from the log is greater than 30 days, then store the corresponding username in $array
    }
    $i = $i + 2
}
```

Now you can access the usernames like `$array[0]`, `$array[1]` and so on. Hope that helps!

NOTE - The regex pattern will change as per the format your usernames are  defined. [Here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=username&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is a `regex library` which might turn out to be helpful.